# Python ConfigParser: input section name as variable

Tags: python, configparser

i want to read data out of a .cnf file. It might have a lot of sections, so I want to read them out automatically. My Code Looks like this:

```
while numberOfSections > 0:
    check = parser.get(numberOfSections, "check")
    hostname = parser.get(numberofSections, "hostname")
    ip = parser.get(numberofSections, "IP")
    port = parser.get(numberofSections, "port")
    request = parser.get(numberofSections, "request")
```

Now unfortunately, it just says "No section: 5". My numberofSections variable in this example is 5, so that's that. The sections are named like this:

```
[1]
check = ''
hostname = ''
IP = ''
port = ''
request = ''

[2]
check = ''
hostname = ''
IP = ''
port = ''
request = ''

[3]
check = ''
hostname = ''
IP = ''
port = ''
request = ''

...
```

So, any ideas? I'm new to python, so please explain it slowly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception `No section: 5` was returned because you are using `while` loop with always `true` argument.

You should use `for` loop, something like:

```
for section in config.sections():
    check = parser.get(section, "check")
    hostname = parser.get(section, "hostname")
    ip = parser.get(section, "IP")
    port = parser.get(section, "port")
    request = parser.get(section, "request")
```

Comment: Thank you, worked fine. Just fyi: I did include a Statement which decreases my Counter, so that was not the reason. Anyways, thank you.